# Transitionning opacity affect the rendering of parent elements

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm working on *some kind* of clock. I have a button that change the opacity of some numbers to 0. When I add a transition, the fade out also affect the parent element (or the sibling, but I guess it's the parent).

```js
const hideClicked = (e) => {
  document.body.classList.toggle("sol-hidden");
};

document.querySelector("#hideNb").addEventListener("click", hideClicked);
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.clock {
  color: #fff;
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 5em rgba(44, 48, 58, 0.3) inset, 0 0 1em 5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}

.tickBoxes div,
.hands div {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.tickBox {
  width: 0;
  height: 15em;
  top: 0;
  left: 15em;
}

.tickBox .tickNum {
  font-size: 3em;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: -0.6em;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.6em inset #333642;
}

.tickBox .tickSol {
  transform-origin: initial;
  left: -0.7em;
  top: 3.3em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1a1b1f;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, opacity 3s;
  user-select: none;
}

.tickBox.active .tickNum {
  animation: numUsed 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.tickBox.active .tickSol {
  background-color: #0ebeff;
}

body.sol-hidden .tickSol {
  /*top: 12em;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;*/
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock" id="clock">
  <div class="tickBoxes">
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(0deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="4">4</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(0deg);">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(27.6923deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="3">3</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-27.6923deg);">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(55.3846deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="6">6</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-55.3846deg);">13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(83.0769deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="4">4</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-83.0769deg);">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(110.769deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="1">1</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-110.769deg);">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(138.462deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="2">2</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-138.462deg);">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(166.154deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="2">2</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-166.154deg);">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(193.846deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="3">3</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-193.846deg);">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(221.538deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="4">4</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-221.538deg);">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(249.231deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="6">6</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-249.231deg);">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(276.923deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="4">4</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-276.923deg);">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(304.615deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="2">2</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-304.615deg);">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tickBox" style="transform: rotate(332.308deg);">
      <div class="tickNum" data-nb="2">2</div>
      <div class="tickSol" style="transform: rotate(-332.308deg);">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="hideNb">hide</button>
```

There's some kind of blur/contraction on the upper numbers (not visible on the number that is not rotated).
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

(This isn't an answer, but posting a comment wouldn't allow me to add an image)

Could you add an image of what you are seeing and how you would like it to look instead? This is what I'm seeing, but I'm not sure what blur/contraction you're referring to

[image]
[image]